Why are Japanese subtitles used only for the isekai world inhabitants in "Suicide Squad Isekai"?
In the anime series Suicide Squad Isekai, as the title suggests, the Suicide Squad gets isekai'd (transported) to a medieval fantasy world. It's revealed that the inhabitants of this isekai world speak a different language from our main characters.
Here's where it gets a bit confusing for me: When the inhabitants of the isekai world speak to someone from our protagonists' world, baked-in/hardcoded Japanese subtitles appear on screen. However, these subtitles do not appear when the locals talk among themselves (like during the queen's cabinet meeting or conversations between Cecil and the princess).

An ogre talking to the Suicide Squad

Cecil talking to the Suicide Squad
I'm watching the show in its original Japanese audio with English subtitles, and to my ears, both the fantasy world inhabitants and our protagonists seem to be speaking Japanese.
What's the deal with the selective baked-in/hardcoded Japanese subtitles? And why are there Japanese subtitles only when the fantasy world locals talk to non-locals?

Could they be speaking with a heavy accent?  I've seen some shows where people speaking Scot-accented or Irish-accent English are subtitled, even though they're speaking perfectly comprehensible English.  I blame Americans.

@DavidW You might be onto something with the accents. However, it's puzzling that there are no Japanese subtitles when the locals talk to each other. Surely their accents would be consistent?

My guess is that they're not speaking Japanese, they're speaking gibberish that sounds Japanese, and the subtitles are to translate the gibberish into Japanese, while making it clear that they're not supposed to be understood. I don't speak Japanese so I have no way to confirm this.

Where are you watching it? I've looked around online, and it seems in the English dub the orc scene you have a screenshot of has the orcs speaking Japanese (with an accent) and the squad speaking English, with the Japanese subtitles; but the subbed version I found has both parties speaking English, with English subs for both (and no baked in Japanese subtitles).

@Showsni The Hulu version, original Japanese audio (not the English dubbed version).

The "other world" language is not in Japanese.
There are many words from different languages in the "other world" language. The writers could have put these together to create a language, as they did in the first Suicide Squad film. Or, as somebody else posted, it could be "a load of gibberish."
I speak and can read some Japanese (kanji is difficult), some Latin, and other languages. I tried to find out what language they are speaking but ended up with more questions than answers.
All the main characters' names in the other world are derived from Latin names:

Cecil - meaning 'sixth' or 'blind'
Fione - meaning 'white,' 'fair'
Aldora - meaning 'winged gift'

Cecil speaks the word "omina" on a few occasions, which is Latin for "made known." This is his first word when meeting the Suicide Squad after they take over the prison. Cecil speaks the word "takshi" before throwing his sword, which means 'to form or create' in Hindi. However, the same word means "what" in the subtitles.

Hi, welcome to SF&F.  I really don't understand how this answers the question about why subtitles aren't used consistently for the same characters.  Please make sure you're answering the question that was asked.

@DavidW I believe I understand the answerer's intent. I've edited their answer to more directly address the question.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! Please consider registering your account, which gives you access to more site features. As a registered user, you will be able to vote, and you won’t lose access to your post if you switch devices or browsers, or when your browser cookies are cleared. Registering is easy and allows you to participate fully in our community. For more info, see Why should I register my account?
